# CSS :after SVG height IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I'm adding a svg to the page like this

```
#ID:after{
 content: url(/images/arrow.svg);
 margin-left: 5px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 7px;
}
```

Now in Chrome and firefox it like this
[image: Chrome]

Now when you take a look in IE11 it looks like this
[image]

How can I make sure the svg is not getting so big in IE?

Comment: use as `background-image` and give `background-size` it will fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Viltorino Fernandes

The fix is as following

First make a blank content 
set a background of your svg
set the width and the height of your svg
add a display inline block to apply the size but keep it inline

Final code:

```
#ID:after{
      content: '';
      background: url(/images/arrow.svg);
      margin-left: 5px;
      width: 10px;
      height: 7px;
      display: inline-block;
}
```